# Style Pandas Columns Separately

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I want to apply separate background gradient to different columns in my pandas dataframe

```
a b c
-----
1 2 3
4 5 6
9 2 3
```

I want one background gradient for column a and a different background gradient to another column as such.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can apply `background_gradient` to each individual column and compose multiple styles in a single call:

```py
df.style\
    .background_gradient(cmap="cool", subset=['a'])\
    .background_gradient(cmap="bone", subset=['b'])\
    .background_gradient(cmap="winter", subset=['c'])
```

[image]